# Evaluate $ \int {(\tan x)}^{\frac{1}{3}} dx $

Tags: indefinite-integrals

Evaluate the following indefinite integral.
$$ \int {(\tan x)}^{\frac{1}{3}} dx $$
How could i do this integral ?

I tried multiplying the numerator by ${(\sec x)}^2$ and denominator by $1+{(\tan x)}^2$ but getting stuck after putting $\tan x=t$.

Comment: I left the exact solution in the linked question.